# How to fix an SSD

Tags: ssd

I have a Samsung 128 go SSD : MZ5PA128HMCD-01000.
When I'm using it : there is always I/O errors.

I tried to secure-erase it.
But it is impossible to create a new NTFS (or any filesystem...) partition because I still get I/O errors.

I tought maybe upgrading the firmware will solve the problem.
Unfortunately, I'm not able to upgrade the firmware with Samsung SSD Magician Tool 
... because Magician says there is no Samsung SSD on my computer...

Is there a way to make Magician recognize this Samsung MZ5PA128HMCD-01000 SSD?
Is another tool available to flash any firmware on a SSD?
What should I do to fix this SSD?

Comment: Does it still have warranty?

Comment: replace the SSD/cables

Comment: It has no more warranty. I already tried to use other SATA cables.

Comment: It sounds like you are out of luck, time to replace the hardware, if there isn't a warranty.

Comment: My Samsung is not gone, but I wonder if anyone could get the firmware updated. The Magician refuses to recognize this disk as Samsung SSD. Seems to be some sort of OEM thing.

Answer (score 1):

If trying other cables failed you may want to try the drive on other SATA ports and other computers to ensure the cause of the issues is the SSD itself. Try other Power cables too.

Check if the drive is recognized in BIOS, [Device Manager](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=lVsXdu), [Disk Management](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=ktLG5g), DiskPart and the Manufacturer tool when connected to another working PC with a cable and to a port that certainly work.

If you get the drive to be recognized try checking the raw values of the S.M.A.R.T. status and see if the drive has any problems.

If all else fails, try contacting the manufacturer's support.

Answer (score 0):

If you get I/O errors it sounds rather like the disk is gone. They should come with two or three years warranty, though, so try contacting the vendor for a replacement.